# How can I make circular Ray and Box Ray in 2D project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using Ray as shown in the picture, the blue Ray changed the Layer when it recognized the water balloon, making it impossible for the player to climb over the water balloon. And the red Ray made it impossible to install multiple water balloons at the same position value. However, using RayCast, diagonal judgments are often ignored once in a while, resulting in an error that allows you to install the water balloon in the same position several times, or that you can climb back onto the water balloon even though you came out of the water balloon.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
void Ray()
{
    if (moveVec.x == 0 && moveVec.y == 1)
    {
        PlusVec = new Vector2(0, 1.41f);
        MakeVec = new Vector2(0, -0.6f);
        dirVec = Vector2.up;
    }
    else if (moveVec.x == 0 && moveVec.y == -1)
    {
        PlusVec = new Vector2(0, -1.41f);
        MakeVec = new Vector2(0, 0.6f);
        dirVec = Vector2.down;
    }
    else if (moveVec.x == -1 && moveVec.y == 0)
    {
        PlusVec = new Vector2(-1.41f, 0);
        MakeVec = new Vector2(0.6f, 0);
        dirVec = Vector2.left;
    }
    else if (moveVec.x == 1 && moveVec.y == 0)
    {
        PlusVec = new Vector2(1.41f, 0);
        MakeVec = new Vector2(-0.6f, 0);
        dirVec = Vector2.right;
    }

    Debug.DrawRay(rigid.position + PlusVec, dirVec * 0.3f, new Color(0, 0, 1));
    rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rigid.position + PlusVec, dirVec, 0.3f, LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon A"));

    if (rayHit.collider != null)
    {
            scanObject = rayHit.collider.gameObject;
            scanObject.gameObject.layer = 10;
            Debug.Log(scanObject.name);
    } else
    {
            scanObject = null;

    }

    Debug.DrawRay(rigid.position + MakeVec, dirVec * 1.2f, new Color(1, 0, 0));
    RaycastHit2D rayHitForMake = Physics2D.Raycast(rigid.position + MakeVec, dirVec, 1.2f, LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon A") | LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon B") | LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon Hard A") | LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon Hard B"));

    if(rayHitForMake.collider != null)
    {
        playerAmakeBalloon = false;
    } else
    {
        playerAmakeBalloon = true;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the blue Ray using CircleCast, but it didn't work as I thought.

```
rayHit = Physics2D.CircleCast(rigid.position, 1f, Vector2.up, LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon A"));
```

I want to make a red ray into a box and a blue ray into a circle, just like I made with Gizmos.
I want to set the border of the box and the circle as the recognition range.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your If statments don't actually allow for diagonals, you'd need 8 of them minimum. You could add to that but it gets a bit of an If-Statement-Hell. What went wrong with the circle-cast?

Comment: Recognizes objects other than the layer I specified. And like I drew with Gizmos, I want to set the position value to the center of the player

Comment: Ok, maybe didn't read the question thoroughly. So, what's actually going wrong with boxcast and spherecast? Is it the layers again?

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstand that. Then do you mean to make RayCast 8 directions?

Comment: Search online for boxcast and spherecast, they sound like just what you want. They are part of Unity. They basically send a giant cube or sphere shaped ray. Or you might want the other similar physics functions like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html that send many rays around a box or sphere shape (but is quite performant still).